# How to fix ('No cipher can be selected.',) when creating context with urllib3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, urllib3

I am making a proxy server and I am tryng to handle HTTPS requests, but I'm facing a problem with setting the ciphers:

```
# Set up SSL/TLS interception logic
# Wrap sockets with SSLContext
context = urllib3.util.ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers='TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384') 
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3  # Disable SSLv2 and SSLv3
```

I am tryng to connect to a server that uses TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher, but when I run the code i got

> ('No cipher can be selected.',)

How can I fix it?